# Rails: Using CanCanCan Abilities to hide elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I'm using the CanCanCan gem. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities) you can define abilities. That is working for me. What I want to do is to limit the access to records, that contain a value. Something like:

```
can :crud, Order, :brand == empty?
```

A User should only be allowed to see the record, if the brand-column of the Order table is empty. As my example doesn't work apparently.. How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right use case for `CanCanCan` - it would be more appropriate to use a specific query in the SQL:

```
#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :no_brand, -> { where(brand: "") }
end

#app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @orders = Order.no_brand
   end
end
```

---

Of course, you *could* use `CanCanCan`, and to do it you'd do [this](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions):

```
#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :read, Order, brand: ""
  end
end
```

The reason why I wouldn't do it is because `CanCanCan` is meant for *authorization* -- checking whether a user has [permission](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/authorization) to do something.

Your use case is best used with SQL query conditions.